# Some terminal commands run via Java don't display output in Linux

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to write a Java program to run terminal command. Googling and SO got me to here:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Detector {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] cmd = {"ls", "-la"};
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            p.waitFor();

        } catch (IOException  | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

So far, so good. The problem is if I try to run a command like "python -V" via

`String[] cmd = {"python", "-V"};`

The program will run, but no output is actually printed out. Any ideas?

Comment: `python -V` by default writes to STDERR, not STDOUT.
Changing it to `python -V 2>&1` should work, but I am sure there is someway to do this in Java without the `2>&1` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you see on your command line when running `python -V` is actually being printed to standard error.  To capture this, you need to use a different `InputStream`, such as this:

```
BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
```

The rest of your code is fine.

Comment: Hey, that did the trick! Thanks very much. Strange how it does that.